# how to change NSCursor and effect on my application

Tags: cocoa

I have obtained the crosshair cursor from NSCursor crosshairCursor. Then, how can i change

to it. I don't want to call enclosingScrollView to setDocumentCursor as

[[view enclosingScrollView] setDocumentCursor:crosshaircursor ];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use the `-set` method of `NSCursor` to set the current cursor:

```
[[NSCursor crosshairCursor] set];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement [a `resetCursorRects` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/resetCursorRects) to send yourself [`addCursorRect:cursor:` mesasges](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/addCursorRect:cursor:). This way, the cursor will automatically change to the crosshair whenever it enters the appointed section of your view.